# open a new webpage when a hyperlink is clicked, and where to set the page in VS

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, html

I have asp.net, and a webpage here:

```
<asp:GridView ID="BalanceCheckDataGridView" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound = "DataGridViewTotalSum" >
  <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company" ItemStyle-Width="20%" >
           <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:HyperLink Text='<%# (Eval("Company"))%>' ID="HyperLink1" Target="_blank" runat="server" 
               NavigateUrl=WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE IF I WANT TO NAVIGATE TO ANOTHER WEBPAGE IN THE SAME SOLUTION
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="30%" DataField="Balance" HeaderText="Balance" />

  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So column“Company” is a hyperlink. when people click on it, i want to show in another webpage or add a gridview of the details information about that company. So, I need to pass the company name to it too.

How should I set the link in the hyperlink field? so that it can navigates to a webpage inside the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: What's not working? You already have `target="_blank"`. Also, what do you mean with `so that it still navigates to a webpage inside the visual studio`?

Comment: @MelanciaUK: hi I updated it just now. thanks.

Comment: its no rocket science, but, you put the path to a page in your solution ideally...any specific issues, then you'll need to elaborate on it...

Comment: @MelanciaUK: It's like, I want to have something like localhost/somepage/newpage   I have done the "somepage", I wonder how I can do the "newpage" and navigate to that one